# Failed to create the metadata.json file

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, volttron

I am trying out the BEMOSS project on the tinker board but I am stuck at the below issue after the installation.

```
2018-04-29 16:44:14,441 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.rpc ERROR: unhandled exception in JSON-RPC method 'start_agent': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linaro/Build/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 168, in method
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linaro/Build/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/control.py", line 137, in start_agent
    self._aip.start_agent(uuid)
  File "/home/linaro/Build/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/aip.py", line 550, in start_agent
    agent_uuid, os.path.join(self.install_dir, agent_uuid, name), name)
  File "/home/linaro/Build/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/aip.py", line 463, in _launch_agent
    metadata = pkg.metadata
  File "/home/linaro/Build/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/packages.py", line 404, in metadata
    with open(os.path.join(self.distinfo, 'metadata.json')) as file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/linaro/.volttron/agents/37eb5289-7f74-43b9-85fe-9037e8a00f2f/approvalhelperagent-0.1/approvalhelperagent-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to newer version of wheel. Reverting to wheel version 0.30 would resolve this issue. Refer to https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/issues/1652

Please update to latest bootstrap.py from develop branch, and run

```
python bootstrap.py --force
```

this should create a new virtual environment folder with the right version of wheel.